# JSONarray parsing showing No value found

Tags: android, json

This is the json which i am getting from a URL

```
{
responce: "success",
data: [
        {
        Breakfast: [
            {
                food_interval: "Breakfast",
                id: "1",
                menu_creator_id: "1",
                item_code: "13",
                food_interval_category_id: "1",
                food_interval_category: "Main Item",
                item_name: "Methi thepal",
                item_quantity: "1",
                unit_id: "1",
                unit_desc: "Number"
            },
            {
                food_interval: "Breakfast",
                id: "2",
                menu_creator_id: "1",
                item_code: "14",
                food_interval_category_id: "2",
                food_interval_category: "Cereals",
                item_name: "Museli",
                item_quantity: "1",
                unit_id: "7",
                unit_desc: "Bowl "
            },
            {
                food_interval: "Breakfast",
                id: "3",
                menu_creator_id: "1",
                item_code: "15",
                food_interval_category_id: "8",
                food_interval_category: "Bread",
                item_name: "Brown Bread",
                item_quantity: "2",
                unit_id: "1",
                unit_desc: "Number"
            },
            {
                food_interval: "Breakfast",
                id: "4",
                menu_creator_id: "1",
                item_code: "16",
                food_interval_category_id: "21",
                food_interval_category: "Butter Cheese",
                item_name: "Cheddar Cheese",
                item_quantity: "1",
                unit_id: "3",
                unit_desc: "Gram"
             }
           ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Code i have tried :

```
String result = response.body().string();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray foodintervalarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
for(int i = 0 ; i < foodintervalarray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = foodintervalarray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray breakfast = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("Breakfast");
    for(int j = 0 ; j < breakfast.length(); j++){
        JSONObject jsonObject2 = breakfast.getJSONObject(j);
        String breakFastMenu = jsonObject2.getString("food_interval");
        Log.i("breakFastMenu","breakFastMenu "+breakFastMenu);
    }
```

But i am getting : No value found for Breakfast array.
After the data array there is a { , so do i need to call JsonObject before calling JsonArray for breakfast ?
Can anybody suggest me what to do

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is an incorrect JSON format. You have to wrap key by " sign. First of all, try this.

Test here : http://jsonlint.com/

E.g., this is correct

```
{
    "responce": "success",
    "data": [{
        "Breakfast": [{
            "food_interval": "Breakfast"
        }]
    }]
}
```

**EDIT**

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class tst {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final String result = "{\"responce\":\"success\",\"data\":[{\"Breakfast\":[{\"food_interval\":\"Breakfast\",\"id\":\"1\",\"menu_creator_id\":\"1\",\"item_code\":\"13\",\"food_interval_category_id\":\"1\",\"food_interval_category\":\"Main Item\",\"item_name\":\"Methi thepal\",\"item_quantity\":\"1\",\"unit_id\":\"1\",\"unit_desc\":\"Number\"},{\"food_interval\":\"Breakfast\",\"id\":\"2\",\"menu_creator_id\":\"1\",\"item_code\":\"14\",\"food_interval_category_id\":\"2\",\"food_interval_category\":\"Cereals\",\"item_name\":\"Museli\",\"item_quantity\":\"1\",\"unit_id\":\"7\",\"unit_desc\":\"Bowl \"},{\"food_interval\":\"Breakfast\",\"id\":\"3\",\"menu_creator_id\":\"1\",\"item_code\":\"15\",\"food_interval_category_id\":\"8\",\"food_interval_category\":\"Bread\",\"item_name\":\"Brown Bread\",\"item_quantity\":\"2\",\"unit_id\":\"1\",\"unit_desc\":\"Number\"},{\"food_interval\":\"Breakfast\",\"id\":\"4\",\"menu_creator_id\":\"1\",\"item_code\":\"16\",\"food_interval_category_id\":\"21\",\"food_interval_category\":\"Butter Cheese\",\"item_name\":\"Cheddar Cheese\",\"item_quantity\":\"1\",\"unit_id\":\"3\",\"unit_desc\":\"Gram\"}],\"10 A. M\":[{\"food_interval\":\"10 A. M\",\"id\":\"\",\"menu_creator_id\":\"\",\"item_code\":\"\",\"food_interval_category_id\":\"\",\"food_interval_category\":\"\",\"item_name\":\"\",\"item_quantity\":\"\",\"unit_id\":\"\",\"unit_desc\":\"\"}],\"11.30 Soup\":[{\"food_interval\":\"11.30 Soup\",\"id\":\"5\",\"menu_creator_id\":\"5\",\"item_code\":\"9\",\"food_interval_category_id\":\"13\",\"food_interval_category\":\"Soup\",\"item_name\":\"Carrot Soup\",\"item_quantity\":\"1\",\"unit_id\":\"7\",\"unit_desc\":\"Bowl \"}],\"Lunch\":[{\"food_interval\":\"Lunch\",\"id\":\"6\",\"menu_creator_id\":\"6\",\"item_code\":\"15\",\"food_interval_category_id\":\"9\",\"food_interval_category\":\"Chapati\",\"item_name\":\"Brown Bread\",\"item_quantity\":\"4\",\"unit_id\":\"1\",\"unit_desc\":\"Number\"}],\"3.30 PM\":[{\"food_interval\":\"3.30 PM\",\"id\":\"\",\"menu_creator_id\":\"\",\"item_code\":\"\",\"food_interval_category_id\":\"\",\"food_interval_category\":\"\",\"item_name\":\"\",\"item_quantity\":\"\",\"unit_id\":\"\",\"unit_desc\":\"\"}],\"7 pm Soup\":[{\"food_interval\":\"7 pm Soup\",\"id\":\"\",\"menu_creator_id\":\"\",\"item_code\":\"\",\"food_interval_category_id\":\"\",\"food_interval_category\":\"\",\"item_name\":\"\",\"item_quantity\":\"\",\"unit_id\":\"\",\"unit_desc\":\"\"}],\"Dinner\":[{\"food_interval\":\"Dinner\",\"id\":\"\",\"menu_creator_id\":\"\",\"item_code\":\"\",\"food_interval_category_id\":\"\",\"food_interval_category\":\"\",\"item_name\":\"\",\"item_quantity\":\"\",\"unit_id\":\"\",\"unit_desc\":\"\"}]}]}";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray foodintervalarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < foodintervalarray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = foodintervalarray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray breakfast = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("Breakfast");
            for(int j = 0 ; j < breakfast.length(); j++){
                JSONObject jsonObject2 = breakfast.getJSONObject(j);
                String breakFastMenu = jsonObject2.getString("food_interval");
                System.out.println("breakFastMenu "+breakFastMenu);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I've tested this JSON.
But if I use JSOUP I obtain 403 error:

```
final String result = Jsoup.connect("http://dieto.vm1.in/api/menu_display_2d.php?date=2016/08/22&diet_type=6&food_category=1&class_type=1").ignoreHttpErrors(true).get().data();
```

You have to check whether you retrieve this JSON inside the code (not in browser).

Comment: http://dieto.vm1.in/api/menu_display_2d.php?date=2016/08/22&diet_type=6&food_category=1&class_type=1

when i test it in jsonlint , it shows me correctly , it also says valid but in my browser it shows differently , why so ?

Comment: @narahari_arjun , updated. check how do you retrieve your json data. Is it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check json validity from http://jsonlint.com/
It it not a valid response right now.

After that, create corresponding  Response.java class and parse it with Gson. Just write the Response.java entity according to your response.After that:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); 
Response r = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Response.class);
```

For more example you can follow this tutorial : 
http://rowsandcolumns.blogspot.com/2013/02/url-encode-http-get-solr-request-and.html

Comment: hey thanx for replying , i am giving you the original link , i just posted a part of it , actually the link i had posted in jsonlint , it shows valid.

In json lint , the Breakfast and the other other sub arrays are shown like this "Breakfast" but i am not able to view like this in my browser , why so ?

http://dieto.vm1.in/api/menu_display_2d.php?date=2016/08/22&diet_type=6&food_category=1&class_type=1

Comment: you can use Postman https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

your json file.html dose not have any tag of html just your json